# fetching elementcollecion from hibernate based on memeber of condition

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, jpql, hibernate-mapping, jpa-2.1

I have two entities Customer & Tester. Where a customer can request for tests and a tester can assign it to itself which will be set to the currentTestId. Also all the test id would be added to assignedTests list for old tests references. Testers have hierarchy as test lab manager, lab employee and whenevr a tester accept the request lab mangers are also assigned the test and so the ManyToOne(customer) and OneToMany(Tester) relationships are added.

DataSet:
[image]

```
Customer Entity

@Column(name = "test_id",nullable = false)
private long testId;

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "tester_id")
private Tester tester;

Tester Entity

@Column(name = "test_id",nullable = false)
private long currentTestId;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "tester")
private Set<Customer> customers = new HashSet<>();

@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name="assigned_tests",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="tester_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
@Column(name="test_id", nullable = false)
private Set<Long> assignedTests = new HashSet<>();
```

Problem Statement:
I want to fetch all customers who are part of the tester assigned tests. So since it is a one to many relation ideally I should have something like this

```
Select c.id from Customer c, Tester t
where c.testId memeber of t.assignedTests
and t.id = :testerId
```

But this gives me the error:
The basic field cannot be used as a state field path

The Query compilation work if I pass the testId but unfortunately in the code I cannot pass it(just tried to test if it will work)

```
Select c.id from Customer c, Tester t
where :testId memeber of t.assignedTests
and t.id = :testerId
```

I am new to JPA and learning how to use ElementCollection. I am using Postgres database and JPA 2.1. Also I cannot use native query or the criteria Api. It has to be using the JPQL but still suggestions would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
 SELECT c.id FROM Customer c 
 JOIN c.tester t
 JOIN t.assignedTests at 
 WHERE t.id = :testerId
```

?

Comment: Hi @Maurice Perry, Thanks for the answer. So sorry i missed to mention the details about the manytoone and onetomany  relationship in the description. I have updated the description and will try your answer.

Comment: Hi @Maurice Perry, it does not work because there is a possibility that a tester is not directly assigned to a customer but can still have access to the test request. In this query we are missing all teseters who have a testId in there assigned tests but dont have an entry as testerId in customer.
the query should be n the format as "Select c.id from Customer c, Tester t"  that is why the need for member of is required